# How to put images into portrait format?

Tags: html, css

How do I set one of my pictures into portrait format? i tried using image orientation and it says property name unknown. I tried rotate 90 and that said the same thing..

css rotate="90", image inherit, webkit transform

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="primary col">
    <img class="josh images" 
         src="https://via.placeholder.com/384x288?text=Joshs+Image" 
         width="288px" height="384px" 
         alt="My Pic" rotate="90">
  </div>
</div>
```

for the image to rotate 90 degrees
The website is www.shaunstanley.co.uk and it's on the portfolio page

Comment: can you create jsfiddle and share

Comment: `transform: rotate(90deg)` or `transform: rotate(-90deg)`

Comment: And this is also not right `width="288px" height="384px" ` there are no px in the image attributes

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS and add a transform rule to your image, such as:

```css
.josh {
  width: 288px;
  height: 384px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="josh" src="https://via.placeholder.com/384x288?text=Joshs+Image">
```

See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mbzqL6e4/1/

If you only want to rotate this specific image, maybe add and use an ID selector instead of a class selector.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Better reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms